# Writing test cases for update JPQL not supported in DataJpaTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, data-jpa-test

```
public interface UserRepository extends JPARepository<User, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update User u set u.active = false where u.userId = :userId")
    void updateEmployee(Integer userId);

.......
}
```

I am new to unit testing. So I am trying to write test cases for JPQL using DataJpaTest for the above repository method. Every time my test case failed when I used the following method to test also I
could not identify where I was making mistakes. If anyone has a solution it would be really helpful to me.
Thanks in Advance.!

In the test case, I wrote, that the field **active** does not get updated and The value is also null.

```
@Test
void updateUserRecord(){
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserId(1);
    userRepository.save(user);
    
    userRepository.updateEmployee(user.getUserId());
    
    assertFalse(user.getActive());
}
```

Comment: Customer is an entity? or User is an entity? JPARepository<User, Long> looks collect, I think.

Comment: @Junhyunny Thank you for your response, yeah you are correct. It is <User, Integer>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using @Modifying, @Query annotation, JPA directly update database. Not update persistent context. So your user instance in test code is not updated. You have to re-fetch from database.

I think using entity manager as a helper makes your test code better.

1. Prepare data with entity manager. After that flush and clear.

- `flush` method reflects entities changes in persistent context to database.
- `clear` method clears persistent context.

2. Update user data
3. Find result from database again.

```java
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.app.User;
import com.example.demo.app.UserRepository;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@DataJpaTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    void flushAndClear() {
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }

    @Test
    void updateUserRecord() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId(1);
        entityManager.persist(user);
        flushAndClear();


        userRepository.updateEmployee(user.getUserId());


        User result = entityManager.find(User.class, user.getUserId());
        assertEquals(false, result.getActive());
    }
}
```

Comment: For my case, entitymanager.persist(user) not working I have used entitymanager.merge(user). But, the solution is only working for userId = 2 not for other values like user.setUserId(3) or other numbers. Thanks for the solution @Junhyunny